# MYSQL/PHP - How to make a "Sort By" dropdown for sorting results drawn from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I would like to include a feature that lets users of my site sort the results of a search, either by name or by price.

This is fairly simple as all i intend on doing is changing the mysql query, via php.

So basically the query looks like this:

```
$searchResultQuery = "
    SELECT id, name, price
    FROM items
    WHERE MATCH (name)
    AGAINST ('{$GLOBALS['input']}' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    ORDER BY $GLOBALS['sort']
";
```

And the html looks something like this:

```
<form>
<select name="sort" id="sort" style="float: left;">
    <option value="name">Name</option>
    <option value="price">Price</option>
</select>
</form>
```

What i want to do, is have the form automatically submit when  a new option is selection. As in, by default the results are ordered by name, but if the user chooses price, then it will adjust the results so display in order of their prices. This would happen without the user needing to click on a submit button of some sort.

As i have a very bleak knowledge of javascript, I have been reading up on some of the html5 additions, and it seems that there is nothing to cover this. Is this possible without the use of javascript or am i forced to learn how to use the `onchange` attribute?

If anyone has any input regarding this, it would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

EDIT:

This would be what i have added to the controller, although i assume this is the reason that is is not being passed:

```
if (isset($_POST['sort']))
{   
    $GLOBALS['sort'] = $_POST['sort'];
}
```

How would i add the forms value to the globals variable?

Comment: Are you confusing Java and Javascript?

Comment: @Sergei Tulentsev No, there is no confusion, just a problem with my wording that has now been corrected, thanks!

Comment: **WARNING!** The accepted answer is [essentially insecure and leads straight to SQL injection!](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/sql_injection_example#escaping) Refer to the answer linked at the top for the proper solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the PHP code (don't forget to escape user input before sending it to DB engine):

```
$pattern = mysql_real_escape_string($GLOBALS['input']);
$sort = mysql_real_escape_string(isset($GLOBALS['sort']) ? $GLOBALS['sort'] : 'name');

$searchResultQuery = "
    SELECT id, name, price
    FROM items
    WHERE MATCH (name)
    AGAINST ('$pattern' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    ORDER BY $sort
";
```

And to automatically submit the form you have to handle select's [`onchange`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) event:

```
<form name="myform">
<select name="sort" id="sort" style="float: left;" onChange="javascript:document.myform.submit();">
    <option value="name">Name</option>
    <option value="price">Price</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, that seems like a simple enough approach, but when applying your suggestion, i am faced with: `Notice: Undefined index: sort in C:\wamp\www\domain\searchResults.html.php on line 29` Any Ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Check your `$searchResultQuery` to see the resulting SQL query; put this after your `$searchResultQuery = "..."` string: `var_dump($searchResultQuery);`

Comment: The query seems to come out fine. As in the variable `sort` is being passed through.

Comment: There is a problem with this too, I have a controller script (index.php) this script includes searchResults.html.php, so basically, when the form has been submitted, it refreshes index.php and the search results are lost. Would i need to store the input values as session variables instead?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've misprinted in `$sort` definition. Please look at my initial reply, I fixed the second line `$sort = ...` (instead of `$GLOBALS['sort'] = ...`)

Comment: It still produces the error, which is the line you mentioned.

Comment: That means that the element with index `sort` is missing in the `$GLOBALS` array. Check that you've put it there before this code.

Comment: I have put in in there, but what would be the right way of doing this, as i dont think i have it right? please see the edit in my original post.

Comment: Yes, your edits will set the `$GLOBALS['sort']` when you pass some value to the script. I updated my code to handle undefined `$GLOBALS['sort']` more correctly. You should do something similar to `$GLOBALS['input']`. And in general it is not the best practice to use `$GLOBALS` extensively. Passing parameters to your function or using OOP is much better.

Comment: Your edit has solved the error, and i have apready done something similiar for the other global variable, but the problem still persists where the index page is being refreshed and the results lost, which brings me back to that... Would it be better to store these as session variables instead?

Comment: If you need to pass that variables between different scripts (say, remember last user choice) - you can store it in a session. Otherwise store them in local objects. I just mean that using global variables is a bad technique for the architecture reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunatly, you cannot submit another query via php without reloading the page. You will have to use javascript. [Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp) is what you're looking for